# Is there a way to prevent injecting a single implementation of an interface that was registered multiple times in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dependency-injection

In my code, there is the registration of two different services with the same interface as this:

```
services.AddSingleton<IServiceResolver, ServiceResolver>();
services.AddSingleton<IService, ServiceA>();
services.AddSingleton<IService, ServiceB>();
```

The `ServiceResolver` is used to pick the correct service based on some circumstances. The `ServiceResolver` itself has a constructor like this:

```
public ServiceResolver(IEnumerable<IService> idServices, ...)
```

So, any business logic related code should always use the service resolver to pick the correct service to use.

**The Problem:**

`IService` can be injected directly into business code and will then be always `ServiceB` since this was the last `IService` registered.

Is there a way to prevent injecting a single implementation of an interface that was registered multiple times?

I know that as long as you stick to just injecting `IServiceResolver` there will be no problem, but the code would be much safer to use if this simple thing could be prevented somehow.

Comment: Is `ServiceResolver` the only class that needs the `IService`s? If so, you could register your various `IService`s directly to the `ServiceResolver` then only register `ServiceResolver`. That would solve your problem at the cost of a little bit of coupling. Edit: I realize my suggestion won't work if any of the `IService`s have other dependencies, derp.

Comment: Not sure there is anything clever you can do. Perhaps use another interface for DI that implements `IService` and do `services.AddSingleton<ISecretService, ServiceA>();`. Make sure nobody uses that interface other than the resolver. Seems a bit hacky. Another solution would be a Roslyn analyser that picks up `IService` in a constructor and make it not compile.

Comment: @aumra.cxg this was my first idea too, but then in the unit tests I can no longer provide a mocked IService to test the resolving functionality. But maybe it is the better tradeoff to not do that and  have the IService not accessible (because one dev actually DI it and this was a hard bug to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a way to do this if no other classes need to resolve any of the `IService`s. You can set up `ServiceResolver` so that it has knowledge about what `IService` types exist and then internally it can manually create all the instances using the existing `ServiceCollection`. To do this, `ServiceResolver` will need `IServiceProvider` and you do lose some functionality, like having scope handled automatically for you.

Here's a quick example of what I mean.

The new `ServiceResolver` class:

```
public class ServiceResolver : IServiceResolver
{
    public static void Register<TService>() where TService : IService
    {
        ServiceTypes.Add(typeof(TService));
    }
    
    public ServiceResolver(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
    
    private IEnumerable<IService> GetServices()
    {
        return ServiceTypes.Select(t => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(_serviceProvider, t) as IService);
    }
    
    private static List<Type> ServiceTypes = new List<Type>();
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
}
```

Registering types:

```
ServiceResolver.Register<ServiceA>();
ServiceResolver.Register<ServiceB>();

services.AddSingleton<IServiceResolver, ServiceResolver>();
```

I created a working example of this [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/78txop)

A modified version where the `IService`s are created as singletons [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Uc31XZ)

Comment: And if `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` have different constructors?

Comment: I was just giving that a try in the Fiddle, I'll post an updated one shortly

Comment: Updated the fiddle to show that the same code works even if the `IService`s have different constructors with dependencies in the main `ServiceCollection`